# Is there a way in R to pivot a flattened hierarchy table into it's full widened output to use for mapping?

Tags: sql, r, hierarchy, cloudera, impala

I have a flattened hierarchy that is about 10 layers deep. There is a key, but unfortunately that key has not been adhered to so cannot be used for my purpose.

I need to take this flat table and turn it into a wide hierarchy, the only relationship I have is the Row Id and the Parent Id.

My data looks like this (simplified);

```
id  name            description     code    sub_level_name  parent_id
1   Parent Company  My Big Company  MBC     Company 
2   Franchise1      My Franchise1   MF1     Franchise       1
3   Store1          My Store1       MS1     Store           2
4   Store2          My Store2       MS2     Store           2
5   Store1Owner     My Store1Owner  MSO1    Store Owner     3
6   Store2Owner     My Store2Owner  MSO2    Store Owner     4
```

And I'd like the result to look like;

```
company_name    company_description   company_code  franchise_name  franchise_description   franchise_code  store_name  store_description   store_code  storeowner_name storeowner_description  storeowner_code
Parent Company  My Big Company        MBC           Franchise1      My Franchise1               MF1  Store1           My Store1        MS1      Store1Owner            My Store1Owner         MSO1
Parent Company  My Big Company        MBC           Franchise1      My Franchise1               MF1  Store2           My Store2        MS2      Store2Owner            My Store2Owner         MSO2
```

Normally I would use pivot_wider and use the sub_level_name column but this is what I was saying has not been adhered to in the larger scope (this table is ~7000 rows and can go 10 deep)

What I feel I need to do is to match the Parent Id to the Id and join the columns on based on their sub_level_name to create the types of columns "x.name, x.description, x.code) and to do this row by row until it hits the top level of the hierarchy.

Greatly for any help with this - doesn't have to be an R solution, and SQL solution would be great also.

Edit: Dput source data

```
structure(list(id = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6), name = c("Parent Company", 
"Franchise1", "Store1", "Store2", "Store1Owner", "Store2Owner"
), description = c("My Big Company", "My Franchise1", "My Store1", 
"My Store2", "My Store1Owner", "My Store2Owner"), code = c("MBC", 
"MF1", "MS1", "MS2", "MSO1", "MSO2"), sub_level_name = c("Company", 
"Franchise", "Store", "Store", "Store Owner", "Store Owner"), 
    parent_id = c(NA, 1, 2, 2, 3, 4)), class = c("spec_tbl_df", 
"tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -6L), spec = structure(list(
    cols = list(id = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
    "collector")), name = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
    "collector")), description = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
    "collector")), code = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
    "collector")), sub_level_name = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
    "collector")), parent_id = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
    "collector"))), default = structure(list(), class = c("collector_guess", 
    "collector")), skip = 1), class = "col_spec"))
```

Comment: could you post a reproducible sample of your data please ( for example with `dput()`)?

Comment: @the_darkside thank you for that example. Hopefully the edit I have made will help.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to create an `id` column for every `sub_level_name`, remove the columns which are not needed and get data in wide format.

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  group_by(sub_level_name) %>%
  mutate(id = row_number()) %>%
  select(-parent_id) %>%
  tidyr::pivot_wider(names_from = sub_level_name, 
                     values_from = c(name, description, code))
```

Comment: Hi Ronak - unfortunately I can't. The key I was alluding to in the top of my post was the sub_level_name column essentially. I can't clean it, I need to rely on the Parent Id to Id relationship to build the hierarchy. Your solution was what I was hoping to do from the start but because of the variance in the hierarchy I cannot.

Comment: @LukeWilliams Can you add few more rows of your data and show exact expected output based on that so that it is easier to understand what you are trying to do.